# Pointer points different data type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I read that if we use pointer, the data type must be the same. But I've test this code, and there is no error. I think there'll be an error there. But nothing happens. The program works like it should be.  Why can we explain this?

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
float i, j, k, l;
int *c1, *c2, c[1];

printf("Enter i : ");
scanf("%f", &i);
printf("Enter j : ");
scanf("%f", &j);
printf("Enter k : ");
scanf("%f", &k);
printf("Enter l : ");
scanf("%f", &l);

c1 = &c[0];
*c1 = i+k;
c2 = &c[1];
*c2 = j+l;
printf("\nMatrice c is [%d ; %d]\n", *c1, *c2);

return 0;
```

}

output :

```
Enter i : 1
Enter j : 2
Enter k : 3
Enter l : 4

Matrice c is [4 ; 6]

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.447 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I've edited this code

```
printf("\nMatrice c is [%d ; %d]\n", *c1, *c2);
```

to become

```
printf("\nMatrice c is [%f ; %f]\n", *c1, *c2);
```

And the output is error.

```
Enter i : 1
Enter j : 2
Enter k : 3
Enter l : 4

Matrice c is [0.000000 ; 42581666233418238000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000]

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 1.164 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: `c2 = &c[1];` - There is no `c[1]`. You're code invokes *undefined behavior* upon dereference of `c2`. The array `c` has one element, and with zero-based indexing, that means `c[0]` is viable. `c[1]` is *not*.

Comment: Array index starts from 0. So how is it possible to access c[1] when the size of the array is 1????

Comment: @WhozCraig so I must change the variable c[1] ?

Comment: @suvojit_007 I think the size of array starts from 0. So the array must be c[2] right?

Comment: If your array size is n then you can access from **0** to **n-1**.

Comment: Yes the array size must be c[2] in order to access c[0] and c[1]

Comment: I honestly don't even know what this code is trying to do (not that it matters). You claimed this "worked" correctly; not true. The undefined behavior I pointed was an originating issue. Another issue comes with your addendum in changing your `printf` format specifiers. Now, on top of the undefined behavior mentioned before, you're *lying* to `printf` by claiming it will be sent two `float`, then sending it two `int` instead (one of which isn't even valid). That's just more *undefined behavior*. If you don't have your compiler warning levels maxed, do so.

Comment: Yout title is "Pointer points different data type" and in the text you also mention pointers with different types. I suppose you want to address "strict aliasing" but there is however nothing in your code where two pointers are of different type.

Comment: Thank you @suvojit_007  for your answer. Actually I'm still new to this array and pointers so I don't really understand how to use them.

Comment: @WhozCraig *I read that if we use pointer, the data type must be the same. But I've test this code, and there is no error.* - I think now he has got his answer. c1 and c2 are pointer to **integer** not **float**

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry but actually i'm new in this lesson so i don't really understand.

Comment: @SALOMO ***What*** is it you don't understand??

Comment: @SALOMO what are you _actually_ trying to do with your code? The code is pretty weird and wrong as already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer all. I will study this material more and more.

Comment: Sorry my code seems so complicated. But now i got the reason.

Comment: @SALOMO `printf("\nMatrice c is [%f ; %f]\n", *c1, *c2);` Oh no, don't. Your `c1` is a pointer to **int**. So `*c1` is an **int**. To print an **int** use `%d`  (As others have mentioned, the problem with your original code is: `int *c1, *c2, c[1];` It shall be `int *c1, *c2, c[2];`

Comment: @SALOMO Your code is not complicated if you want to demonstrate something by using arrays and pointers. Otherwise just `int i_and_k = i + k; int j_and_l = j + l; printf("[%d; %d]\n", i_and_k, j_and_l);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int* c1;    //pointer to int
int c[1];   //int array with one element
c1 = &c[0]; // c1 points to the the first and only element of the array.

c[0] = 5;   // the first element of the array c is 5
*c1 = 5;    // The element to which the pointer is pointing is 5 (dereferencing)
```

In your code, the problem is that the array size is not enough.
There is no element `c[1]` so the behavior is undefined.

This results in `segmentation fault` most often but you were unlucky.

Declare the array `c` as `int c[2];`.

Also, note what does the `[]` operator.
If you define a variable it shows how much elements would this array hold - how much memory should be allocated.

In expression `array[N]` is the same as `*(array + N)`